# Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$injector/modulerr?p0=mean&p1=%5B%24injector%3Amodulerr%5D%20http%3A%2F

Tags: angularjs, bower, mean

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$injector/modulerr?p0=mean&p1=%5B%24injector%3Amodulerr%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.5.0%2F%24injector%2Fmodulerr%3Fp0%3Dmean.circles%26p1%3D%255B%2524injector%253Amodulerr%255D%2520http%253A%252F%252Ferrors.angularjs.org%252F1.5.0%252F%2524injector%252Fmodulerr%253Fp0%253Dmean.users%2526p1%253D%25255B%252524injector%25253Amodulerr%25255D%252520http%25253A%25252F%25252Ferrors.angularjs.org%25252F1.5.0%25252F%252524injector%25252Fmodulerr%25253Fp0%25253Dangular-jwt%252526p1%25253D%2525255B%25252524injector%2525253Anomod%2525255D%25252520http%2525253A%2525252F%2525252Ferrors.angularjs.org%2525252F1.5.0%2525252F%25252524injector%2525252Fnomod%2525253Fp0%2525253Dangular-jwt%2525250AH%2525252F%2525253C%25252540http%2525253A%2525252F%2525252Flocalhost%2525253A3000%2525252Fbower_components%2525252Fangular%2525252Fangular.min.js%2525253Fv%2525253D8c9ac3aa67fee6aa599b4624398feba7%2525253A6%2525253A416%2525250Ake%2525252F%2525253C%2525252F%2525253C%2525252F%2525253C%25252540http%2525253A%2525252F%2525252Flocalhost%2525253A3000%2525252Fbower_components%2525252Fangular%2525252Fangular.min.js%2525253Fv%2525253D8c9ac3aa67fee6aa599b4624398feba7%2525253A25%2525253A136%2525250Ab%25252540http%2525253A%2525252F%2525252Flocalhost%2525253A3000%2525252Fbower_components%2525252Fangular%2525252Fangular.min.js%2525253Fv%2525253D8c9ac3aa67fee6aa599b4624398feba7%2525253A24%2525253A188%2525250Ake%2525252F%2525253C%2525252F%2525253C%25252540http%2525253A%2525252F%2525252Flocalhost%2525253A3000%2525252Fbower_components%2525252Fangular%2525252Fangular.min.js%2525253Fv%2525253D8c9ac3aa67fee6aa599b4624398feba7%2525253A24%2525253A1%2525250Ag%2525252F%2525253C%25252540http%2525253A%2525252F%2525252Flocalhost%2525253A3000%2525252Fbower_components%2525252Fangular%2525252Fangular.min.js%2525253Fv%2525253D8c9ac3aa67fee6aa599b4624398feba7%2525253A39%2525253A287%2525250An%25252540http%2525253A%2525252F%2525252Flocalhost%2525253A3000%2525252Fbower_components%2525252Fangular%2525252Fangular.min.js%2525253Fv%2525253D8c9ac3aa67fee6aa599b4624398feba7%2525253A7%2525253A353%2525250Ag%25252540http%2525253A%2525252F%2525252Flocalhost%2525253A3000%2525252Fbower_components%2525252Fangular%2525252Fangular.min.js%2525253Fv%2525253D8c9ac3aa67fee6aa599b4624398feba7%2525253A39%2525253A135%2525250Ag%2525252F%2525253C%25252540http%2525253A%2525252F%2525252Flocalhost%2525253A3000%2525252Fbower_components%2525252Fangular%2525252Fangular.min.js%2525253Fv%2525253D8c9ac3aa67fee6aa599b4624398feba7%2525253A39%2525253A304%2525250An%25252540http%2525253A%2525252F%2525252Flocalhost%2525253A3000%2525252Fbower_components%2525252Fangular%2525252Fangular.min.js%2525253Fv%2525253D8c9ac3aa67fee6aa599b4624398feba7%2525253A7%2525253A353%2525250Ag%25252540http%2525253A%2525252F%2525252Flocalhost%2525253A3000%2525252Fbower_components%2525252Fangular%2525252Fangular.min.js%2525253Fv%2525253D8c9ac3aa67fee6aa599b4624398feba7%2525253A39%2525253A135%2525250Ag%2525252F%2525253C%25252540http%2525253A%2525252F%2525252Flocalhost%2525253A3000%2525252Fbower_components%2525252Fangular%2525252Fangular.min.js%2525253Fv%2525253D8c9ac3aa67fee6aa599b4624398feba7%2525253A39%2525253A304%2525250An%25252540http%2525253A%2525252F%2525252Flocalhost%2525253A3000%2525252Fbower_components%2525252Fangular%2525252Fangular.min.js%2525253Fv%2525253D8c9ac3aa67fee6aa599b4624398feba7%2525253A7%2525253A353%2525250Ag%25252540http%2525253A%2525252F%2525252Flocalhost%2525253A3000%2525252Fbower_components%2525252Fangular%2525252Fangular.min.js%2525253Fv%2525253D8c9ac3aa67fee6aa599b4624398feba7%2525253A39%2525253A135%2525250Ag%2525252F%2525253C%25252540http%2525253A%2525252F%2525252Flocalhost%2525253A3000%2525252Fbower_components%2525252Fangular%2525252Fangular.min.js%2525253Fv%2525253D8c9ac3aa67fee6aa599b4624398feba7%2525253A39%2525253A304%2525250An%25252540http%2525253A%2525252F%2525252Flocalhost%2525253A3000%2525252Fbower_components%2525252Fangular%2525252Fangular.min.js%2525253Fv%2525253D8c9ac3aa67fee6aa599b4624398feba7%2525253A7%2525253A353%2525250Ag%25252540http%2525253A%2525252F%2525252Flocalhost%2525253A3000%2525252Fbower_components%2525252Fangular%2525252Fangular.min.js%2525253Fv%2525253D8c9ac3aa67fee6aa599b4624398feba7%2525253A39%2525253A135%2525250Afb%25252540http%2525253A%2525252F%2525252Flocalhost%2525253A3000%2525252Fbower_components%2525252Fangular%2525252Fangular.min.js%2525253Fv%2525253D8c9ac3aa67fee6aa599b4624398feba7%2525253A43%2525253A164%2525250AAc%2525252Fc%25252540http%2525253A%2525252F%2525252Flocalhost%2525253A3000%2525252Fbower_components%2525252Fangular%2525252Fangular.min.js%2525253Fv%2525253D8c9ac3aa67fee6aa599b4624398feba7%2525253A20%2525253A449%2525250AAc%25252540http%2525253A%2525252F%2525252Flocalhost%2525253A3000%2525252Fbower_components%2525252Fangular%2525252Fangular.min.js%2525253Fv%2525253D8c9ac3aa67fee6aa599b4624398feba7%2525253A21%2525253A259%2525250A%25252540http%2525253A%2525252F%2525252Flocalhost%2525253A3000%2525252Fbower_components%2525252Fweb-bootstrap%2525252Findex.js%2525253Fv%2525253D2738ecbd5273ee77f02ee08d77eaa20e%2525253A9%2525253A3%2525250An.Callbacks%2525252Fi%25252540http%2525253A%2525252F%2525252Flocalhost%2525253A3000%2525252Fbower_components%2525252Fjquery%2525252Fdist%2525252Fjquery.min.js%2525253Fv%2525253D6fc159d00dc3cea4153c038739683f93%2525253A2%2525253A27060%2525250An.Callbacks%2525252Fj.fireWith%25252540http%2525253A%2525252F%2525252Flocalhost%2525253A3000%2525252Fbower_components%2525252Fjquery%2525252Fdist%2525252Fjquery.min.js%2525253Fv%2525253D6fc159d00dc3cea4153c038739683f93%2525253A2%2525253A27828%2525250A.ready%25252540http%2525253A%2525252F%2525252Flocalhost%2525253A3000%2525252Fbower_components%2525252Fjquery%2525252Fdist%2525252Fjquery.min.js%2525253Fv%2525253D6fc159d00dc3cea4153c038739683f93%2525253A2%2525253A29619%2525250AJ%25252540http%2525253A%2525252F%2525252Flocalhost%2525253A3000%2525252Fbower_components%2525252Fjquery%2525252Fdist%2525252Fjquery.min.js%2525253Fv%2525253D6fc159d00dc3cea4153c038739683f93%2525253A2%2525253A29804%2525250A%25250AH%25252F%25253C%252540http%25253A%25252F%25252Flocalhost%25253A3000%25252Fbower_components%25252Fangular%25252Fangular.min.js%25253Fv%25253D8c9ac3aa67fee6aa599b4624398feba7%25253A6%25253A416%25250Ag%25252F%25253C%252540http%25253A%25252F%25252Flocalhost%25253A3000%25252Fbower_components%25252Fangular%25252Fangular.min.js%25253Fv%25253D8c9ac3aa67fee6aa599b4624398feba7%25253A40%25253A60%25250An%252540http%25253A%25252F%25252Flocalhost%25253A3000%25252Fbower_components%25252Fangular%25252Fangular.min.js%25253Fv%25253D8c9ac3aa67fee6aa599b4624398feba7%25253A7%25253A353%25250Ag%252540http%25253A%25252F%25252Flocalhost%25253A3000%25252Fbower_components%25252Fangular%25252Fangular.min.js%25253Fv%25253D8c9ac3aa67fee6aa599b4624398feba7%25253A39%25253A135%25250Ag%25252F%25253C%252540http%25253A%25252F%25252Flocalhost%25253A3000%25252Fbower_components%25252Fangular%25252Fangular.min.js%25253Fv%25253D8c9ac3aa67fee6aa599b4624398feba7%25253A39%25253A304%25250An%252540http%25253A%25252F%25252Flocalhost%25253A3000%25252Fbower_components%25252Fangular%25252Fangular.min.js%25253Fv%25253D8c9ac3aa67fee6aa599b4624398feba7%25253A7%25253A353%25250Ag%252540http%25253A%25252F%25252Flocalhost%25253A3000%25252Fbower_components%25252Fangular%25252Fangular.min.js%25253Fv%25253D8c9ac3aa67fee6aa599b4624398feba7%25253A39%25253A135%25250Ag%25252F%25253C%252540http%25253A%25252F%25252Flocalhost%25253A3000%25252Fbower_components%25252Fangular%25252Fangular.min.js%25253Fv%25253D8c9ac3aa67fee6aa599b4624398feba7%25253A39%25253A304%25250An%252540http%25253A%25252F%25252Flocalhost%25253A3000%25252Fbower_components%25252Fangular%25252Fangular.min.js%25253Fv%25253D8c9ac3aa67fee6aa599b4624398feba7%25253A7%25253A353%25250Ag%252540http%25253A%25252F%25252Flocalhost%25253A3000%25252Fbower_components%25252Fangular%25252Fangular.min.js%25253Fv%25253D8c9ac3aa67fee6aa599b4624398feba7%25253A39%25253A135%25250Ag%25252F%25253C%252540http%25253A%25252F%25252Flocalhost%25253A3000%25252Fbower_components%25252Fangular%25252Fangular.min.js%25253Fv%25253D8c9ac3aa67fee6aa599b4624398feba7%25253A39%25253A304%25250An%252540http%25253A%25252F%25252Flocalhost%25253A3000%25252Fbower_components%25252Fangular%25252Fangular.min.js%25253Fv%25253D8c9ac3aa67fee6aa599b4624398feba7%25253A7%25253A353%25250Ag%252540http%25253A%25252F%25252Flocalhost%25253A3000%25252Fbower_components%25252Fangular%25252Fangular.min.js%25253Fv%25253D8c9ac3aa67fee6aa599b4624398feba7%25253A39%25253A135%25250Afb%252540http%25253A%25252F%25252Flocalhost%25253A3000%25252Fbower_components%25252Fangular%25252Fangular.min.js%25253Fv%25253D8c9ac3aa67fee6aa599b4624398feba7%25253A43%25253A164%25250AAc%25252Fc%252540http%25253A%25252F%25252Flocalhost%25253A3000%25252Fbower_components%25252Fangular%25252Fangular.min.js%25253Fv%25253D8c9ac3aa67fee6aa599b4624398feba7%25253A20%25253A449%25250AAc%252540http%25253A%25252F%25252Flocalhost%25253A3000%25252Fbower_components%25252Fangular%25252Fangular.min.js%25253Fv%25253D8c9ac3aa67fee6aa599b4624398feba7%25253A21%25253A259%25250A%252540http%25253A%25252F%25252Flocalhost%25253A3000%25252Fbower_components%25252Fweb-bootstrap%25252Findex.js%25253Fv%25253D2738ecbd5273ee77f02ee08d77eaa20e%25253A9%25253A3%25250An.Callbacks%25252Fi%252540http%25253A%25252F%25252Flocalhost%25253A3000%25252Fbower_components%25252Fjquery%25252Fdist%25252Fjquery.min.js%25253Fv%25253D6fc159d00dc3cea4153c038739683f93%25253A2%25253A27060%25250An.Callbacks%25252Fj.fireWith%252540http%25253A%25252F%25252Flocalhost%25253A3000%25252Fbower_components%25252Fjquery%25252Fdist%25252Fjquery.min.js%25253Fv%25253D6fc159d00dc3cea4153c038739683f93%25253A2%25253A27828%25250A.ready%252540http%25253A%25252F%25252Flocalhost%25253A3000%25252Fbower_components%25252Fjquery%25252Fdist%25252Fjquery.min.js%25253Fv%25253D6fc159d00dc3cea4153c038739683f93%25253A2%25253A29619%25250AJ%252540http%25253A%25252F%25252Flocalhost%25253A3000%25252Fbower_components%25252Fjquery%25252Fdist%25252Fjquery.min.js%25253Fv%25253D6fc159d00dc3cea4153c038739683f93%25253A2%25253A29804%25250A%250AH%252F%253C%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A3000%252Fbower_components%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253Fv%253D8c9ac3aa67fee6aa599b4624398feba7%253A6%253A416%250Ag%252F%253C%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A3000%252Fbower_components%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253Fv%253D8c9ac3aa67fee6aa599b4624398feba7%253A40%253A60%250An%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A3000%252Fbower_components%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253Fv%253D8c9ac3aa67fee6aa599b4624398feba7%253A7%253A353%250Ag%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A3000%252Fbower_components%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253Fv%253D8c9ac3aa67fee6aa599b4624398feba7%253A39%253A135%250Ag%252F%253C%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A3000%252Fbower_components%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253Fv%253D8c9ac3aa67fee6aa599b4624398feba7%253A39%253A304%250An%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A3000%252Fbower_components%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253Fv%253D8c9ac3aa67fee6aa599b4624398feba7%253A7%253A353%250Ag%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A3000%252Fbower_components%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253Fv%253D8c9ac3aa67fee6aa599b4624398feba7%253A39%253A135%250Ag%252F%253C%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A3000%252Fbower_components%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253Fv%253D8c9ac3aa67fee6aa599b4624398feba7%253A39%253A304%250An%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A3000%252Fbower_components%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253Fv%253D8c9ac3aa67fee6aa599b4624398feba7%253A7%253A353%250Ag%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A3000%252Fbower_components%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253Fv%253D8c9ac3aa67fee6aa599b4624398feba7%253A39%253A135%250Afb%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A3000%252Fbower_components%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253Fv%253D8c9ac3aa67fee6aa599b4624398feba7%253A43%253A164%250AAc%252Fc%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A3000%252Fbower_components%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253Fv%253D8c9ac3aa67fee6aa599b4624398feba7%253A20%253A449%250AAc%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A3000%252Fbower_components%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253Fv%253D8c9ac3aa67fee6aa599b4624398feba7%253A21%253A259%250A%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A3000%252Fbower_components%252Fweb-bootstrap%252Findex.js%253Fv%253D2738ecbd5273ee77f02ee08d77eaa20e%253A9%253A3%250An.Callbacks%252Fi%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A3000%252Fbower_components%252Fjquery%252Fdist%252Fjquery.min.js%253Fv%253D6fc159d00dc3cea4153c038739683f93%253A2%253A27060%250An.Callbacks%252Fj.fireWith%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A3000%252Fbower_components%252Fjquery%252Fdist%252Fjquery.min.js%253Fv%253D6fc159d00dc3cea4153c038739683f93%253A2%253A27828%250A.ready%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A3000%252Fbower_components%252Fjquery%252Fdist%252Fjquery.min.js%253Fv%253D6fc159d00dc3cea4153c038739683f93%253A2%253A29619%250AJ%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A3000%252Fbower_components%252Fjquery%252Fdist%252Fjquery.min.js%253Fv%253D6fc159d00dc3cea4153c038739683f93%253A2%253A29804%250A%0AH%2F%3C%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3Fv%3D8c9ac3aa67fee6aa599b4624398feba7%3A6%3A416%0Ag%2F%3C%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3Fv%3D8c9ac3aa67fee6aa599b4624398feba7%3A40%3A60%0An%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3Fv%3D8c9ac3aa67fee6aa599b4624398feba7%3A7%3A353%0Ag%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3Fv%3D8c9ac3aa67fee6aa599b4624398feba7%3A39%3A135%0Ag%2F%3C%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3Fv%3D8c9ac3aa67fee6aa599b4624398feba7%3A39%3A304%0An%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3Fv%3D8c9ac3aa67fee6aa599b4624398feba7%3A7%3A353%0Ag%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3Fv%3D8c9ac3aa67fee6aa599b4624398feba7%3A39%3A135%0Afb%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3Fv%3D8c9ac3aa67fee6aa599b4624398feba7%3A43%3A164%0AAc%2Fc%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3Fv%3D8c9ac3aa67fee6aa599b4624398feba7%3A20%3A449%0AAc%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3Fv%3D8c9ac3aa67fee6aa599b4624398feba7%3A21%3A259%0A%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fbower_components%2Fweb-bootstrap%2Findex.js%3Fv%3D2738ecbd5273ee77f02ee08d77eaa20e%3A9%3A3%0An.Callbacks%2Fi%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fbower_components%2Fjquery%2Fdist%2Fjquery.min.js%3Fv%3D6fc159d00dc3cea4153c038739683f93%3A2%3A27060%0An.Callbacks%2Fj.fireWith%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fbower_components%2Fjquery%2Fdist%2Fjquery.min.js%3Fv%3D6fc159d00dc3cea4153c038739683f93%3A2%3A27828%0A.ready%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fbower_components%2Fjquery%2Fdist%2Fjquery.min.js%3Fv%3D6fc159d00dc3cea4153c038739683f93%3A2%3A29619%0AJ%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fbower_components%2Fjquery%2Fdist%2Fjquery.min.js%3Fv%3D6fc159d00dc3cea4153c038739683f93%3A2%3A29804%0A
```

angular...98feba7 (line 6, col 416)

The error appears in http://localhost:3000/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js?v=6fc159d00dc3cea4153c038739683f93. I have tried installing ngRoute,checking angular versions and even reinstalled bower. I don't seem to find what is the module not added/installed?

Comment: can you share the dependency injection for the controller to see how you add the camera reference there?

Answer (score 0):

Are you testing this code on a mobile device?
With ionic serve command Camera will be undefined, it is managed by a cordova plugin.